# Unable to install r-base in ubuntu16

Tags: r

I have removed my R 3.2 version in ubuntu16 and tried to install a new version (R 3.4). I have a problem with the installation because I am no able to re-install the r-base. here is the error:
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation :

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 r-base : Dépend: r-base-core (>= 3.4.2-2zesty) mais ne sera pas installé
          Dépend: r-recommended (= 3.4.2-2zesty) mais ne sera pas installé
          Recommande: r-base-html mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».

Could you help me because I am lost for that. 
Thank you in advance

---

after this code: apt-cache policy r-base-core r-recommended, here the output:

```
r-base-core:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : 3.4.2-2zesty
 Table de version :
     3.4.2-2zesty 500
        500 https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ Packages
     3.4.2-2xenial2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.2-1zesty1 500
        500 https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ Packages
     3.4.1-2zesty0 500
        500 https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ Packages
     3.4.1-1zesty0 500
        500 https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ Packages
     3.4.0-1zesty 500
        500 https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/ Packages
     3.2.5-1precise0 500
```

Comment: Please post your messages in english. 16.04 is not zesty. You have wrong packages. Please update your post with output of `apt-cache policy  r-base-core r-recommended`.

Comment: The version of my ubuntu is french that's way the text error is in french. I have done the apt-cache policy r-base-core r-recommended. And the result is this:     500 http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ Packages
     3.0.1-1precise0 500
        500 http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ Packages
     3.0.0-2precise 500
        500 http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/ Packages
     2.15.3-1precise0precise1 500

Comment: The error is not yet corriged

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS I installed R from R-Cran with the following actions

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-cran.list
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

EOF

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

But at first you should determine from where you got packages from zesty. Or simple remove them with `sudo apt-get purge  r-base r-base-core r-recommended`.

**Update 1**:
First of all: if you use Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) you should not use packages from 17.04 (zesty). 
You should find packages installed from zesty (for example with Synaptic in *Origin* tab), then disable it in */etc/apt/sources.list*. 
Also I recommend to remove marutter PPA with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:marutter/rrutter`. Then start over.

**Update 2**:
Try to find other R packages from zesty with `dpkg -l | grep zesty` and carefully remove them with `apt-get purge`. Please update your question with output of `ls -alt /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

Comment: I have typed that sudo apt-get purge  r-base r-base-core r-recommended but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Le paquet « r-base-core » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « r-base » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
Le paquet « r-recommended » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.

Comment: See update above.

Comment: I have done these step but the problem is not yet resolved

Comment: See update 2 above. Please delete your today's "answer". I see your comments.